# Natural Language ou ChatBot

Tags: natural-language, chatbot

Boa tarde, iniciei esta pergunta mais como uma discussão do que dúvida da linguagem em si.

Preciso fazer um chatbot ou utilizar algum serviço que ofereça isso.
Estava estudando natural language mas achei um site chamado wit.ai
que já oferece esse serviço.

O que não não consigo fazer é criar as entradas para ele neste site
Gostaria de saber se alguém já fez isso e qual plataforma utilizou ou se tem alguma documentação que possa me auxiliar na criação de um chat bot para agendamento de consultas.

A parte que já esta feita é o meu web service, que envia para o chatbot o texto por ex:

```
Gostaria de marcar uma consulta para o dia 27/04
```

ou

```
Gostaria de marcar uma consulta para o dia vinte e sete de março
```

o chat bot deveria me devolver a data formatada o motivo q é consulta ( ou agendamento ou outro motivo que o sistema possa a ter. para que eu processe esta informação trate através de consulta no meu db e devolva para o cliente a resposta.